# Bower: Updating Angular and Its Dependencies

Tags: angularjs, bower

So I'm using a pretty old version (1.2) of Angular in my app and would like to update it to at least 1.3.5. There's a bunch of other packages in my `bower.json` file that depend on that version of Angular.

`bower update` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Is there a quick and easy way to upgrade my version of Angular and have the rest of my packages follow suit?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Run this command first:

```
npm install bower-update -g
```

then run:

```
bower-update
```